# How to make inner border radius?

Tags: html, css

How to make this shape by HTML & CSS inner rounded border radius?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Try this

HTML:

```
<div class="shape"></div>
```

CSS:

```
.shape{
    background: #074b7e;
    width: 300px;
    height: 150px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
 }

 .shape:before{
     content: '';
     width: 150px;
     height: 150px;
     background: #fff;
     position: absolute;
     top: 0;
     right: -75px;
     border-radius: 100%;
 }
```

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/s2oew522/

Comment: thank you very much

Comment: @MinaMedhat Please mark this answer as accept.